# How to prove that all points of a curve $r(t)=\langle t,-t,{t^2\over 2}\rangle$ belong to one plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, proof-explanation

> Prove that all points of a curve expressed by the vector function $r(t)=\langle t,-t,{t^2\over 2}\rangle$ belong to one plane.

We need to find a plane of form $ax+by+cz+d=0$, that is: 
$$
at-bt+c\cdot {t^2\over 2}+d=0
$$
The plane equation holds for any $t$, in particular:
$$
t=0\Rightarrow d=0\\ \quad t=1\Rightarrow c=0\Rightarrow a=b\\a=b\Rightarrow ax+ay=0\Rightarrow x+y=0
$$
That is we received the plane $x+y=0$, now if we plug in the point $\langle t,-t,{t^2\over 2}\rangle$ in the equation $x+y=0$ we can see that all the points belong to the plane.

**My questions**:

1) How do we get that $c=0$? First we suppose that $t=0$ then $d=0$ that totally makes sense. But how does $t=1$ lead to $c=0$? Also each time we're supposing different value for $t$ so $d=0$ only for particular value of $t$ so why will it hold for any point?

2) Why the fact that we got $x+y=0$ mean that all points belong to that plane?

Comment: If you know differential geometry - One way would be to show that the torision is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessary to plug in $t=0$ and $t=1$. It is easier to compare the coefficients. You suppose
$$
0=at-bt+\frac{c}2t^2+d=\frac{c}2t^2+(a-b)t+d
$$
for all $t$. You can see the LHS as a polymial too:
$$
0t^2+0t+0=\frac{c}2t^2+(a-b)t+d.
$$
LHS=RHS implies that the coefficients have to be the same and that yields
$$
\frac{c}2=0\\a-b=0\\d=0.
$$
Finally you get the plane $ax+ay=0$ which is the same as $x+y=0$.

This is also a plane. Consider
$$
x+y=0\Leftrightarrow 1\cdot x+1\cdot y+0\cdot z=0
$$
and you can check that $r$ is in the plane $x+y=0$ because
$$
r_1(t)+r_2(t)=t+(-t)=0.
$$

Comment: Your way to get the plane equation is much simpler and more intuitive. But I didn't understand that last equation. Does $r_1(t)$ mean the first element of the curve $r(t)=\langle t,-t,{t^2\over 2}\rangle$. So $r_3(t)={t^2\over 2}$?

Comment: It is a common notation to use the index at a vector for the component. So $r(t)=\begin{pmatrix} r_1(t)\\r_2(t)\\r_3(t)\end{pmatrix}$. And a vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ belongs to the plane, defined by $x+y=0$ if $v_1+v_2=0$.